# Usage of "such as" with "and"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, commas, such

In the following sentence, is the usage of **"such as"** correct if I would like that "Waze" and "LocoPing" be considered as examples of both Location-based services(LBSs) and Proximity-based applications? also should I put a comma before "such as" and "that"?

> In recent years, we have seen the emergence of a new trend of location-based services (LBSs) and proximity-based applications such as Waze, LocoPing that require users to share their locations.

Comment: The quote communicates your intentions quite well.

Comment: I think the details obscure the real Question, unless *Usage of “such as” with “and”* was a mistake.

Several queries: Why not *Waze and LocoPing*? Why *LBS(s)* but not *PBA(s)*?

More, is the real question whether the trend is for LBS and PBA, both including Waze and LocoPing…

or for LBS and PBA, Waze and LocoPing being examples of PBA?

Answer (score -1):

Such as introduces examples, or things we mention. We would also place a comma before "such as" when we introduce a list, such as in your sentence.